# Can't add new Smarty plugins

Tags: php, smarty

Directory structure:

```
smarty
------plugins
------myplugins
---------------function.myfnc.php
```

in file function.myfnc.php:

```
function smarty_function_myfnc($params, &$smarty) {
   ///code here
}
```

add plugin:

```
$smary->addPluginsDir(/path/to/myplugins);
```

but, when i call in file display.tpl:

```
{myfnc p="value"}
```

this is error:

```
Call to undefined function smarty_function_myfnc()
```

somebody can help me?

Comment: Where is your `display.tpl` located and how does the `include` in that file look like?

Comment: I've added plugin after initialization smarty object

Answer (score 0):

Probably problem is your path to your plugins dir. You should add before your `myplugins` the same path as you use for requiring `Smarty.class.php`.

For example I have code:

```
<?php

require 'smarty/Smarty.class.php';

$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->setTemplateDir('templates');

$smarty->addPluginsDir('smarty/myplugins');

var_dump($smarty->getPluginsDir());


echo $smarty->fetch('temp.tpl');
```

At the beginning I have `require 'smarty/Smarty.class.php';` - my path to `Smarty.class.php` is `smarty` so when I have folder `myplugins` which is inside `smarty` folder as in your case I need to use `smarty/myplugins` and not only `myplugins`.

And then I have `templates/temp.tpl` file with content:

```
{myfnc p="value"}
```

and file `smarty/myplugins/function.myfnc.php` with content:

```
<?php

function smarty_function_myfnc($params, Smarty_Internal_Template $template)
{                           

    return strtoupper($params['p']);
}
?>
```

And output for template is `VALUE` with capital letters as defined in my function.

So as you see it works without a problem.